# Javamelody with alfresco

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, monitoring, alfresco

I installed javamelody on alfresco-tomcat, I used 2-tier architecture (APP and BDD), but when I run my http: // localhost: 8080 / share / monitoring server, it gives me false information , Javamelody counts the users logged in as soon as there is a request for authentication page and no dashboard, which gives me no real data.

Cordially.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of Alfresco, you could install the related plugin:
https://github.com/javamelody/alfresco-javamelody/releases

You can get more accurate information looking at your mbeans via jmx or via javamelody. The number of ticket issues can be found under:

mbeans > Alfresco > RepoServerMgmt > TicketCountAll and TicketCountNonExpired